# PowerBI: how do you calculate the difference between two columns in matrix

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I have a matrix defined as the values : 
[image: Pivot table with Multiple-Level Columns]

I wanted to run a difference between the values that is seen on each date from Baseline and Scenario1 (it can be more than 2) 
So the columns are defined as : 
(1) Date 
(2) Type

So the difference is from Baseline for each Date much as what we do in Calculation - Difference in Excel or Tablaeu

Does anybody have any materials where I can follow through? 
I have the following DAX but it does not give me the result I expect :

```
Diff = 
VAR currIndexDate = MIN (Date [TotalRundate]) 
VAR currIndexType = "Scenario1" 

var currVolume = 
CALCULATE ( SUM (Data[TotalVolume]), 
      FILTER( ALLSELECTED (Data) , Data[TotalRunDate] = currIndexDate && Date[Type] = currIndexType ),
      VALUES (Data[Type]), VALUES (Data[TotalRunDate])
)
var prevVolume = 
CALCULATE ( SUM (Data[TotalVolume]), 
      FILTER( ALLSELECTED (Data) , Data[TotalRunDate] = currIndexDate && Date[Type] <> currIndexType ),
      VALUES (Data[Type]), VALUES (Data[TotalRunDate])
)
RETURN 
IF (prevVolume <> BLANK , currVolume - prevVolume, currVolume)
```

Here is the result that I am getting which sums everything and not within the same grouping of Data[Type] Data[TotalRunDate]

[image: Output Received]

What I want to accomplish is this type: (which is the Difference Calculation in Excel)

[image: Excel Results]

Comment: Don't use VAR, use MEASURE. Try again. https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/defining-variables-in-dax-queries/

Comment: @HilaDG - your comment makes no sense.

Comment: @RADO - VAR doesn't behave as you'd expect it to behave. It's always an issue. Each time you write a VAR you need to check if the results are actually what you want them to be. Also, for the sake of the question: could you please post in the results that you're getting?

Comment: Can you please show columns in visual u"re using and desired outcome (in excel)?

Comment: @Pavel Klammert I added expected outputs that I am trying to duplicate that I get from Excel Pivot to PowerBI.. hope you can help...

Comment: Try to create a difference measure as:
difference = CALCULATE ( SUM (Data[TotalVolume]), 
      FILTER( Data , Date[Type] <> "Baseline")) - CALCULATE ( SUM (Data[TotalVolume]), 
      FILTER( Data , Date[Type] <> "Scenario 1"))

Comment: @Pavel did not solve the problem.. it is giving me one answer across the board -:(

Comment: In that case i don't think ill be able to help you, unless trying it mysleft. Can u provide sample dataset or pbi?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding: Show difference between column-header Type and Type=Baseline, without affecting any other context.

```
Volume = SUM ( 'Data'[TotalVolume] )
```

```
Diff from Baseline =
[Volume] - CALCULATE ( [Volume], 'Data'[Type] = "Baseline" )
```

You don't need to do anything special to preserve filtering context. Just use `CALCULATE` to change the bit of context you care about.