# Power BI : Matrix Get the difference of two columns

Tags: matrix, pivot, powerbi

I am trying to figure out how to get the difference of two columns within a row in Matrix 
everything that was available in the community has been hardcoding the values of the column label. 
I would like to get it more programmatically 
Here is my starting matrix.. i need a difference for each row from baseline column and scenario 1 column

Hope somebody can point me to the right direction

[image: Matrix Value]

Comment: Please post an image of your data model; explain what these two columns are (are they measures? if yes, provide their DAX formulas). A data sample would help too, to reproduce your setup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerBI: how do you calculate the difference between two columns in matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729037/powerbi-how-do-you-calculate-the-difference-between-two-columns-in-matrix)

Comment: @RADO, the other examples are in the other post that Pavel but most of the suggestions did not solve the problem ..

Comment: @EB - I saw the other post, but it does not provide what I asked either. It's impossible to give you a good advice without seeing/understanding your data model (tables and their relations). It's also very hard to help blindly, without a data sample to work with. Ideally, if you prepare and share a sample pbix file that represents your problem (without violating data privacy, of course), most likely you will receive good answers.